# Defining a type to be a `Comparable` in Dart

Tags: oop, dart

This question might stem from an inadequate understanding of OOP in Dart, but anyway:

I've been working on a project for which one of my base classes extends `ListBase` from `dart:collections`. It is useful in some cases I come across to be able to get the sorted indices of these List-like objects (without actually sorting them).

As a parent class I have something like (heavily simplified):

```
abstract class A<T> extends ListBase<T> {
  List<T> internalList;
  List<int> orderedIndices();

  ...

}
```

An example descendant is something like:

```
class B extends A<num> {

  ...

  @override
  List<int> orderedIndices() => new List<int>.generate(
    internalList.length,(i) => i)..sort(
      (i, j) => internalList[i].compareTo(internalList[j]));
}
```

For example, if an instance of `B` has `[1, 5, 2, 4, 3]` as its `internalList` then `orderedIndices` will return `[0, 2, 4, 3, 1]`, as expected.

I would like to put the code that implements `orderedIndices` into class `A`'s definition, however, because it would be identical in any of `A`'s descendants as long as the specified type `T` is `Comparable` (i.e. has `compareTo` defined). I don't know how do this, however, because without knowing the type `T`, Dart has no way of knowing whether `T` instances are indeed `Comparable` and coughs at the `compareTo` if I try to put the code in `A`'s definition.

Although it would work, I balk at the idea of copy-and-pasting code into descendants of the same class... Is there some way I can tell Dart in my definition of `A` that `T` will be a `Comparable`?

Comment: What does it buy you to know that `T` is comparable? The ordering is implemented in `compareTo` of `T`. To get your expected result you would need a different `compareTo` implementation - in your above example a different implementation for type `int` which isn't possible.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I'm not sure I fully understand you. The implementation for type `int` would be the same. For example, if `C` extends `A<int>` (or `A<String>` or `A<Any Comparable>`), then to get the ordered indices from an instance of `C`, I would need to copy-and-paste that code - as it is - from the definition of `B` into the definition of `C`. My question is: surely this would be bad OOP practice and the functionality should be implemented in the parent class?

Comment: Before we talk about making the implementation available to other classes, we should first be able to make it work in one class. I don't think we are there yet ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I think that at least one of "we" are already there. :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : Ah - I think I see what the misunderstanding is. Notice that I'm not trying to sort the lists in the above code but to get the *sequence of indices* that would sort the lists...

Comment: I see. You got a great answer already anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit `T` of `A` to types that are comparable. That's done by putting a bound on `T`:

```
abstract class A<T extends Comparable<T>> extends ListBase<T> {
  ...
  List<int> orderedIndices() => new List<int>.generate(
    internalList.length,(i) => i)..sort(
      (i, j) => internalList[i].compareTo(internalList[j]));
  ...
```

If not all version of `A` are comparable, then you can't do that. Then you can make a helper-subclass of `A` which is:

```
abstract class ComparableA<T extends Comparable<T>> extends A<T> {
   List<int> orderedIndices() => new List<int>.generate( ....
   ...
}
```

Then you can do `class B extends ComparableA<num> ...` to share the comparison behavior when it's possible, and classes extending `A` directly will need to make their own implementation of the method.

Finally, you could change your specifiation of `orderedIndices` to:

```
List<int> orderedIndics(int Function(T, T) compare) {
  return List.generate(internalList.length,(i) => i)..sort(
      (i, j) => compare(internalList[i], internalList[j]));
}
```

Then you can choose per invocation how to compare the elements of `internalList`. If `T` is `Comparable`, you can use `Comparable.compare` as the implementation.

Comment: Nice! I don't need any of the descendants to wrap lists of non comparable objects, but that's great information too.